# What is the quickest way to implement a blog into a pre-existing page?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

For example, in-lining the most recent blog entry into the homepage, and then having the blog archive on a separate page that can be clicked-through to.

Currently there is no blog, and I am pretty agnostic as to how to implement it. It will be just myself writing to it, and comments would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <iframe src="http://your.wordpress.org/blog/url/here"></iframe>
```

is the most straightforward way I can think of.

Comment: Alternately: add a RSS-reader module to your homepage (reading the wordpress rss feed).  Or replace your homepage with a customized wordpress homepage (the feasibility of this depends on how much content you have on your current homepage)